# Best practices for vertically aligning flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm curious to discover the best way of spacing out flex items vertically inside a div. I want the  tag to have more space between its siblings, hence why I've added a flex-grow of 3. But the text inside the flex items isn't vertically aligning in the centre.

Why aren't they vertically aligning in the center? And is there a better way of spacing these out vertically anyway?

Curious to know the best practices from everyone, even if it's a different way.

```css
#test {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
}
a {
  flex-grow: 3;
  background: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: pink;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>
  <span>stuff</span>
  <span>more stuff...</span>
  <a href='#'>link</a>
  <span>even more stuff</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning flexbox properties to the children elements, which are still just inline elements (instead of flexbox elements).

```css
#test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  
  padding: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 200px;
}

#test > * {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  flex-grow: 3;
  background: red;
}
span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>
  <span>stuff</span>
  <span>more stuff...</span>
  <a href='#'>link</a>
  <span>even more stuff</span>
</div>
```